# DropDownList Binding Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am just trying to bind values to a dropdownlist control. I could see no of examples but it is not working for me. Please find my code and the error and help me to solve this.

//My model

```
public class SubjectModel
{
    public int selectedid {get;set;}
    public List<SelectListItem> ddllist{get;set;}
    public SubjectModel()
    {
        ddllist = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
}
```

//My controller

```
public ActionResult DropDownTest()
{

    SubjectModel model = new SubjectModel();
    model.ddllist.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Physics", Value = "1" });
    model.ddllist.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Chemistry", Value = "2" });
    model.ddllist.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Mathematics", Value = "3" });

    model.selectedid = 0;

    return View(model);        
}
```

//My View

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<DopDownBinding.Models.SubjectModel>"%>    

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>DropDownBinding</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="ip">

        <p>
            <label for="timezone">Subjects</label>

            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedid, new SelectList(Model.ddllist, "SubCategoryId", "SubCategoryName", Model.selectedid))
        </p>
    </section>
</body>
```

I am getting this error while executing this.

> An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

I am new to MVC and please help me correct if something is wrong.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `ddllist` property in `SubjectModel` class is a `List<SelectListItem>`, you don't need to do `new SelectList(Model.ddllist, "SubCategoryId", "SubCategoryName", Model.selectedid)` for the second argument of `@Html.DropDownListFor` helper.

Change this syntax

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.selectedid, 
             new SelectList(
                 Model.ddllist, 
                 "SubCategoryId", 
                 "SubCategoryName", 
                 Model.selectedid))
```

to this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedid, Model.ddllist)
```

You also need to remove the second line

```
<%@Page 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<DopDownBinding.Models.SubjectModel>"%>
```

and add this syntax to the first line

```
@model DopDownBinding.Models.SubjectModel
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this is again throwing another error. 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' has no applicable method named 'DropDownListFor' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.
. I tried to cast it like (SelectListItem) Model.ddllist. But a different exception occurs.

Comment: After casting it throws another exception 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownListFor' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor<TModel,TProperty>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty>>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Am I missing something in my view. Should I include something else for using dropdownlist control?

Comment: Are you using razor engine for your view? The second line of the view code looks like ASP.NET MVC 2

Comment: Yes. I am using Razor engine. I included that second line just to try to fix the error. However adding/removing that code doesnt make any difference

Comment: You don't need that second line if you're using Razor engine. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your dropdown in Razor should be

```
//Model.ddllist is selectlist for your dropdown
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedid, Model.ddllist)
```